# Shutdown/reboot freezes

Tags: 20.04, shutdown, freeze, reboot, atheros

this is my first time on this forum. I have a problem on my ubuntu installation, every time I restart or shut down my computer it freezes. Every time I get the error that I attach below, I have been using Ubuntu for years and this is the first time that I have not been able to solve this problem. My computer is a 4th generation intel i7 with 16gb of RAM. My laptop hardware info [here](https://pastebin.com/PNYY4Fx1).

[Screenshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R86hv.jpg)

I appreciate any comments to solve this problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have a device plugged into your SD card at all times? From the looks of the error, the SD reader is losing power (as part of the shut down process) before `/oldroot` is unmounted. As a result, when the OS tries to unmount that device, there is no SD reader anymore and the system waits ... and waits ... and waits ... until it times out.

There are a couple of options for you:

1. Remove SD cards before shutting down
2. Add a script that runs whenever you shut down (or restart) the computer to first unmount any SD cards before initiating the shut down sequence